# Does interface has to be explicitly defined?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am looking at [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359122/dependency-injection-alternatives)

```
 private IDataContextFactory DataContextFactory { get; set; }
```

How does the compiler know that this property is interface?

Comment: Well it knows that the property *type* is an interface because it will resolve `IDataContextFactory` at compile-time. But the compiler doesn't really *care* that it's an interface. It's very unclear what the motivation for your question is.

Comment: Yes, any type you use (except for anonymous types) needs to be explicitly defined *somewhere*. For that code to compile, it must be able to resolve `IDataContextFactory`, and when it resolves it, it will find that it is declared as an `interface`

Comment: @JonSkeet I do not understand if it is a must to define interface as a separate entinty or not.If you take a look at the example,I think that the compile should care it it is interface or not.

Comment: @R.SImovic: Yes, the compiler won't care whether it's an interface or not. But yes, you do need to define the type somewhere - you can't just write `private IFooBarBaz SomeProperty { get; }` without `IFooBarBaz` being defined. It's really unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok,thanks,I understand now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler knows that property `DataContextFactory` is `IDataContextFactory` because that is what you typed in your class.

It then knows that `IDataContextFactory` is an interface IF (that is not in your listing) it is declared as

```
public interface IDataContextFactory{
// something here
}
```