# How do I pass a ILogger<T> into a object created with new?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I want to pass a logger into a constructor of an object. Normally, the logger is dependency injected into a class, but I want to log inside a class that is not dependency injected.

I have a .NET Core worker service. In that service, I have 0-many instances of a class that are created at runtime. I also want to be able to log messages to the logger inside that class.

In my example, I can pass the ILogger that I get from inside the TimedWorker, but the type is wrong.

Currently, I have:

```
    class TimedWorker : BackgroundService
    {
        private List<Dog> m_dogs;
        private ILogger<TimedWorker> m_logger;
        private IConfiguration m_configuration;

        public TimedWorker(ILogger<TimedWorker> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            m_logger = logger;
            m_configuration = configuration;
        }

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            m_dogs= new List<Dogs>();
            List<DogOption> dogOptions= new List<DogOption>();
            m_configuration.GetSection("Dogs").Bind(dogOptions);

            foreach(DogOption option in dogOptions)
            {
                m_dogs.Add(new Dog(option, m_logger));
            }
        } 

    ///...

    }

    class Dog {
        public string Name { get; }
        private int Age;
        private ILogger m_logger;

        public Dog(DogOption option, ILogger logger)
        {
            m_logger = logger;

            Name = option.Name;
            Age = option.Age;

            m_logger.LogInformation($"Dog '{Name}' created");
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when it logs, the logger is of type TimedWorker, not Dog. So when I look at the logs, they are labeled under TimedWorker instead of Dog. I do not know how to pass in a ILogger into the Dog class. Any advice?

Comment: `m_logger` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere

Comment: I will fix the code. I was trying to create a minimum working example and forgot to put that in

Comment: Whose `ILogger<T>` are you using and does it have a "rebind" (or equivalent) method?

Comment: If you don't need manage different log scope, inject just `ILogger` and no `ILogger<T>`.

Comment: I would like to since it helps with debugging

Comment: Your `Dog` class depends on a logger. Since `TimedWorker` is responsible for creating those instances, it should transitively depend on that logger.

Comment: Does  regular approach of adding dependency on creator function work for you?

Comment: @madreflection why? Or rather why do you think OP's requirement to `TimedWorker` to be factory of `Dog`?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I'm not saying it's optimal, just that it would solve the problem.  "Should" may have been the wrong auxiliary verb.

Comment: @madreflection Dog is created in more than one place. Sometimes it's in the TimedWorker class, other times it's in a Controller, Hub, or different Service, which is why I don't want to just depend on TimedWorker

Comment: @ChadK: Nowhere did I suggest that it should.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm not sure what you mean by creator function

Comment: @madreflection I thought that's what you meant by saying Dog should transitively depend on TimedWorker's logger

Comment: No, I said that `TimedWorker` should transitively depend on `ILogger<Dog>`.

Comment: `TimedWorker` accepts and saves both loggers, and then passes the dog logger to the `Dog` constructor.

Comment: So I should inject ILogger<Dog> and ILogger<TimedWorker> into TimedWorker?

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359122/dependency-injection-alternatives shows dependency on factory, but you can just use `Func<Dog>` as dependency...

Answer (score 5):

You can inject the `IServiceProvider` and resolve the dependency manually.

You can do it like this:

```cs
public class Worker
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public Worker(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var specificLogger = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ILogger<Dog>)) as ILogger<Dog>;

        var dog = new Dog(specificLogger);
    }
}
```

```
public class Dog
{
    public Dog(ILogger<Dog> logger)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Hello");
    }
}
```

This creates the specific log based on the class.

`2020-11-18 18:41:58.1275||INFO|ConsoleApp.Dog|Hello`

Answer (score 4):

You can create a logger directly. For example:

```
var logger = LoggerFactory.Create(options => {}).Create<Worker>();
```

Comment: I had to use a different method at the end of the chain, `CreateLogger<T>` instead of `Create<T>`.  `var logger = LoggerFactory.Create(options => {}).CreateLogger<Worker>()`